# Pyinstaller with kivy - No module named 'kivy_deps'

Tags: python, kivy, conda, pyinstaller

I am attempting to create an executable with Kivy using pyinstaller. I am following the official instructions from Kivy. But when attempting to run the .spec file I get the error No module named 'kivy_deps'. Specifically when I add this line to the .spec file

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

I've installed everything with anaconda and I get no issues when running the actual python file. I've tried ignoring the sdl2 and glew instructions and pysintaller runs without issues. But the .exe won't start. A black screen will flash and then close.

Packages installed:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller 
conda install -c conda-forge kivy
conda install -c anaconda pandas
```

Am I missing some dependencies that don't come with the conda package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to not use Anaconda. When I tried with native python everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the missing dependancies from pip by running:

```
pip install kivy-deps.sdl2
pip install kivy-deps.glew
```

For some reason conda does not install those by default